# what is it an activity window in churn model?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification, moving-window, churn

I know that in a churn model many times you define an observation window (historic data) and a performance window (also dependent window, or response window).

I have read an [article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/9109662) that the authors (Khodadadi et al., 2020) also defined an activity window- "The model is
trained based on the data for those who are active in an
Activity window". The next figure is from this article:

[image: Churn windows in the literature]

Can anyone please explain to me the definition and the meaning of the activity window and **why is it necessary?**